# I do not understand how this overload is resolution "works"

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class where the constructor is overloaded for different data types. A simplified example which illustrates the problem is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class c {
public:

    c(const std::string& n, int v) :
        name(n),
        int_value(v)
    {
        std::cout << "Running <int> constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    c(const std::string& n, double v, const std::vector<double>& extra_args) :
        name(n),
        double_value(v)
        args(extra_args)
    {
        std::cout << "Running <double> constructor" << std::endl;
    }



private:
    std::string name;
    int int_value;
    double double_value;
    std::vector<double> args;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    c i("name", int());

    // This line should in my opinion not compile at all; but
    // it ends up calling the (std::string&, int) constructor. 
    c d("name", double());
}
```

as you can see the constructor taking a `double` argument expects and additional `std::vector<double>` argument. My expectation was that the `c::c("name", double())` call should not  compile at all - and I was counting on the compiler to help me in the refactoring process, but instead the constructor taking an integer argument is invoked, and then things go belly up later.

So when I compile and run the example program the output is:

```
Running <int> constructor
Running <int> constructor
```

whereas I was not expecting it to compile at all.

Comment: I guess the compiler should give a warning that it's casting a double to an int.

Comment: Apparently it is a better match, other overload requires more args, and double can be converted transparently to int. As a side note, in 2019 you don't pass arguments by const references to only make copies of them, you pass them by value and construct members with `std::move`.

Comment: You can use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_integral` with the int overload to prevent implicit conversion from `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For overload resolution, a compiler first has to check that an overload can accept the number of arguments that were provided at the call. This is a process that determines which functions are *viable* for this function call expression.

The first overload can only accept exactly two, while the second overload can only accept exactly three. The immediately disqualifies the second overload in both cases. So the overload set contains a single member for both invocations.

Now a compiler has to see if it can form a conversion sequence from every argument to every parameter type. The `"name"` literal gets converted to a `std::string` via constructor, and a `double` has an implicit conversion to `int`. So forming conversion sequences is a success for the one and only overload in the set. As such, it gets called.

Comment: @user422005 If you want to avoid implicit conversions and make it fail to compile, you can declare the constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: I tried using `explicit` - but then it compiled as it "should not".

Comment: @user422005 Ah I just realized that it does not work. I think `explicit` is to avoid the class instance implicit conversion and not for the parameters. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

`double` can get implicitly converted into `int`, which allows the 1st constructor to be called.

If you want to make sure someone won't call it while passing a `double`, you can explicitly delete it.

```cpp
class c {
public:
  c(const std::string& n, double d) = delete;
.
.
.
};

int main(){
  c a{"A", 1); // ok, calls c(const std::string& n, int i);
  //c b{"B", 1.0); Compile error! tries to call deleted function 
  //               c(const std::string& n, double d)
  c b{"C", static_cast<int>(1.0)}; //ok, calls c(const std::string& n, int i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the `=delete;` helped me get the compiler errors I wanted.